# implementing neural networks using c vs using c++?

Tags: c++, c, neural-network

I'm imlementing Neural Networks using C language for a class. I haven't programmed with C++ nor with C for a long time. I started my first couple implementations using C language and it was a pain in the neck!
Now, I am not sure is it because of the language or its how NN is with any language??
BTW, we are not allowed to use any NN toolbox or libraries.

Some people told me its much easier to do it in C++. But I am in a very tight schedule and I'm afraid I might waste "valuable" time transitioning to C++ to find out the benefit is marginal!

So I thought you might guide me into this? Will it be worth it (time efficiency wise) to switch to C++ or not?

Thanks

Comment: Neural networks are pretty advanced concepts. Shouldn't you already be an experienced programmer before tackling this? The language shouldn't be the stumbling block.

Comment: I'm an experienced web developer. And there is nothing in my question related to the complexity of programming! If you are an experienced programmer you should have known the difference between that and the complexity of "implementation" using this language or that!

Comment: If you want to sell it as a library and there is a scope of modification / enhancement of functionality. you should opt C++.
 
If you are doing it for some research purpose or your another application needs it and there may not be major modification in future, you can use c/c++. I mean to say oops is not nuch important

Comment: Check the following library: https://sourceforge.net/projects/c-c-neural-networks/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transitioning to C++ could be worth your time, especially if you've already developed some Object Oriented skills and understanding (even if not with the C++ language itself). However if OO is difficult for you, then the transition may cause more harm than good. It depends on you as a programmer.

The transition won't be as hard as you think. In my opinion, it's less like learning a new language altogether, but instead more like learning new features to a language. Keep in mind that all C code you write will still compile in C++ (mostly, I think? See Kitsune's comment on this answer) because C++ is almost a superset of C.

There's no... direct benefit, so to speak. You can still solve the problem in C, but C++ and Object Orientation may help you create a better, more sharable and understandable solution as although I don't know so much about Nueral Networks, I'm pretty sure some of the characteristics can be neatly abstracted thanks to Object Orientation.

Then again, if OO isn't your peice of cake, then this may end up making it even harder for you. Consider your strengths as a programmer: could you draw a class diagram to figure out how everything fits together comfortably? Do you have a good understanding and appreciation of OO concepts like interfacing and abstraction? If not, then OO could do more harm than good.

Comment: C++ isn't a *strict* superset of C, but it's fairly close. Some C code isn't valid C++ code, and C++ compilers are usually a bit more anal than C compilers (that was part of the reason GCC switched from compiling as C to compiling as C++).

Comment: -1 for talking about OO (a term that has no clear meaning) without mentioning a single benefit or how it could help in this case.

Comment: You are right 2unco! It's not about the difference in language terms/statements between c and c++! Its the difference between OO and none OO programming, which is why C++ (or any object oriented language) would be better(easier) than C to implement Neural Network models.

Answer (score 2):

Just like any other programming task (that doesn't rely on some framework which is only available in 1 language), there is no magical advantage gained by using a special language for Neural Networks.

If you agree that writing code in C++ in general is much easier than writing code in C, then writing Neural Networks code in C++ is much easier than writing Neural Networks code in C. But that is a highly opinion based topic.